# In Java -D what does the D stand for?

Tags: java, properties

What does the D in

```
-Dproperty=value
```

Set a system property value.

Of the [Java application launcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/java.html#options) stand for? For some reason it's been bothering me, why D?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I've always assumed it was to *define* the value of a property... possibly a legacy from C compilers, which often use `-D` as similar to `#define` in code.

EDIT: The closest I have to a source for this at the moment is [some JDK 1.1 documentation](http://www.tns.lcs.mit.edu/manuals/java-1.1.1/tooldocs/win32/java.html) which specifies the flag as:

> **Redefines** a property value. propertyName is the name of the property whose value you want to change and newValue is the value to change it to. [...]

That at least contains the word "redefine" which is close to "define" :)

Comment: I would be interested in seeing a source for this, if it exists.

Comment: Hi Jon, this isn't completely related to this question, but I can't find this info anywhere else, I've read from the docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html `java -Dmydir="some string" SomeClass` the part of `SomeClass` which class is it referring to? I'm using it to get an external `.properties` file modify certain attributes on my program, using Spring, Struts2 and Tomcat 8.5. My thoughts are that it's referring to the class with the `main` method, but in my case no `main` method exists as it's a web application, could you explain it to me?

Comment: @Frakcool: Yes, it's the entry point for the process. When you run Tomcat, you don't generally invoke it in that way though. I suggest you ask a new question with more details about what you're asking.

Answer (score 26):

In C/C++ compilers the similar syntax is used to define preprocessor macros from the command line:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    printf(GREETING);
    return 0;
}
```

.

```
gcc hello.c -DGREETING="\"Hello, world\""
```

Java doesn't have a preprocessor, but properties defined with `-D` are ofter used for the similar reason - to pass some program-specific information about the current environment. The only difference is that in Java we pass them in runtime, not in compile-time:

```
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("greeting"));
    }
}
```

.

```
java -Dgreeting="Hello, world" Hello
```

I think this similarity is the source of similar syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the C/C++ details, it makes sense the -D was carried forward from there.

Answer (score 11):

The reason is **D** stands for **DEFINE**, because what that command switch does is defining variables.

Answer (score 3):

It might be for `Define`, cause you are defining a property