# JVM Options while running Tomcat8 using startup.bat on windows

Tags: java, tomcat8, startup, jvm-arguments

I want provide some JVM options to my application. The application is a web application and packaged as war. I am using Tomcat8 to deploy this war. I want to provide JVM options while running tomcat using statup.bat file.

I can run the application successfully using eclipse. The eclipse Server configuration has provision to supply JVM arguments using launch configuration.

I tried below ways to supply JVM options.

1. Using setenv.bat in bin directory with command `set JAVA_OPTS="........."`.
   example - I tried below commands in `setenv.bat` file separately.

```
    set JAVA_OPTS="-Ddp.registry.local=false -Ddp.registry.logon.id=dpconf -Ddp.registry.logon.pwd=password-Ddp.registry.host.address=ltest16.sto1.3s.intern -Ddp.registry.appid=1234 -Ddp.registry.execunit=BillingDataProvider -Ddp.registry.instance=bdp -Ddp.registry.instance.lowercase=bdp -Ddp.registry.host.port=3700 -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger -Djava.util.prefs.PreferencesFactory=com.smarttrust.common.mechanism.prefs.RegistryJasapPreferencesFactory -Ddp.log.root=C:/Users/dir/softools/apache-tomcat-8.0.5/logs -Ddp.server.log.root=C:/Users/dir/softools/apache-tomcat-8.0.5/logs -Dota.sc.log.root=C:/Users/dir/softools/apache-tomcat-8.0.5/logs -Dlog4j.configuration=file:C:/Users/dir/softools/apache-tomcat-8.0.5/logs/log4j.xml -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:/Users/dir/softools/apache-tomcat-8.0.5/logs/bdp-log.properties"
```

```
    set CATALINA_OPTS="-Ddp.registry.local=false -Ddp.registry.logon.id=dpconf -Ddp.registry.logon.pwd=password -Ddp.registry.host.address=ltest16.sto1.3s.intern -Ddp.registry.appid=1234 -Ddp.registry.execunit=BillingDataProvider -Ddp.registry.instance=bdp -Ddp.registry.instance.lowercase=bdp -Ddp.registry.host.port=3700 -Dorg.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger -Djava.util.prefs.PreferencesFactory=com.smarttrust.common.mechanism.prefs.RegistryJasapPreferencesFactory -Ddp.log.root=C:/Users/dir/softools/apache-tomcat-8.0.5/logs -Ddp.server.log.root=C:/Users/dir/softools/apache-tomcat-8.0.5/logs -Dota.sc.log.root=C:/Users/dir/softools/apache-tomcat-8.0.5/logs -Dlog4j.configuration=file:C:/Users/dir/softools/apache-tomcat-8.0.5/logs/log4j.xml -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:/Users/dir/softools/apache-tomcat-8.0.5/logs/bdp-log.properties"
```

2. exporting the JAVA_OPTS like `set JAVA_OPTS="....."` on command prompt before running `startup.bat`. Above commands exported on command prompt before running startup.bat.
3. Using context.xml file for example  -

```xml
        <context>
         .....................
        <Environment name="dp.registry.local" value="false" type="java.lang.String"/>
         ........................
        </context>
```

But no luck. I am not sure what mistake I am doing.

Comment: Have you prefixed with `-D`? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44745261/why-do-jvm-arguments-start-with-d

Comment: You may need to use `CATALINA_OPTS` instead.

Comment: @Thomas Timbul No , i am not using -D. I tried by using CATALINA_OPTS from command prompt, but it is not working

Comment: When you say "not working" - would you mind giving a specific example of an argument that you've added, and how you're confirming whether it is working or not?

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: @ThomasTimbul  issue was, we don't have use double quotes while exporting the JAVA_OPTS /CATLINA_OPTS variable at commend prompt. I removed the quotes and it worked.  Echoing the value of JAVA_OPTS variable from catlina.bat gave up the clue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Fantastic if you managed to solve this issue. If you'd like you could write this as your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is with double quotes. While exporting from command prompt do not use double cotes. Just do set JAVA_OPTS=-D..... -D....    Space separated list of options.

If you echo the java_opts from catlina.bat , it will give you a clear picture.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that you use CATALINA_OPTS, see comments in `catalina.bat`.

Secondly, VM options need to be individually prefixed with `-D`, for example:

**Linux/Unix Shell:**

```
CATALINA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true \
               -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
               -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
               -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.40.10"
```

As noted in comments, the multiline escape character in windows batch is `^`, and for some reason there's no need to add the double quotes.

**Windows bat/cmd**

```
CATALINA_OPTS=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true ^
               -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false ^
               -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false ^
               -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.40.10
```

Comment: I used both ways, with -D and without -D, both ways are not working. Also I used CATALINA_OPTS setenv.bat, like set CATALINA_OPTS=" -D...... -D....... -D...." that is not working too.

Comment: Your example is a shell based example. He is using Batch. The line separator would be ^ and there is no need to double quote because that's how batch works (it somehow).