# Tomcat10 is not running on Window11 pro (a window opens and closes upon running startup.bat)

Tags: tomcat, startup, windows-11, catalina, tomcat10

I am trying to run Tomcat10 on my PC having Window's 11 Pro.
Upon running startup.bat, a window just opens and closes without showing a running server.
All JRE_HOME, JAVA_HOME, CATALINA_HOME, CATALINA_BASE are set correctly.

Upon running "**catalina configtest**" I have found the following errors:

`Using CATALINA_OPTS:   "" Unrecognized option: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.`

[output on the command prompt after running "**catalina configtest**"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Mj62.png)

Now couldn't figure out how to fix this configuration issue to get the server running.

I want to understand the reason for the errors, so I can fix them.

Comment: i think the problem is in the CATALINA_OPTS; which I tried to set using the command prompt while looking on [this thread about JVM options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58768474/jvm-options-while-running-tomcat8-using-startup-bat-on-windows).

Comment: Use Java 11 or newer. The official listing of Tomcat versions and related compatible Java versions can be found [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html).

Comment: "_I want to understand the reason_" - Your specific error relates to Java modules - which were [introduced in Java 9](https://www.oracle.com/ca-en/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html). See also [Migrating From JDK 8 to Later JDK Releases](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/migrate/index.html#JSMIG-GUID-7744EF96-5899-4FB2-B34E-86D49B2E89B6), where `--add-opens` is discussed. So, basically, your config was trying to use a flag which does not exist in Java 8.

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't work, as the JAVA_OPTS was set as:  
-Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources -D-add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED -D-add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED -D-add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED -D-add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED -D-add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED

Comment: Searching for a recent JRE is a red herring. I think this counts as a new question (but probably one which may already have an answer somewhere on SO). My best suggestion: Describe how you installed Java 11 (and why not just go with a more up-to-date version, anyway?); describe how you installed Tomcat 10.1; describe how you launch Tomcat - and what value (if any) is set for `%JAVA_HOME%`.  Finally, describe any errors you get when launching Tomcat. (If it helps: for me, I have my `%JAVA_HOME%` set to `C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.4.8-hotspot`.) https://adoptium.net/

Comment: Regarding "_a window just opens and closes..._" - Depends exactly how you try to launch Tomcat, but my suggestion (in case you are not already doing this): (1) Open a command prompt. (2) `cd` to the Tomcat installation directory and then into its `bin` directory. (3) Type the command `startup.bat`. You should stand a better chance of seeing the immediate startup error that way. If you just double-click on the `startup.bat` file in a file explorer, you may have the problem you described (window flashes open and then closes too fast to see any errors).

Comment: tried both but in vain

Comment: Tried what _exactly_?

Comment: I mean, no success after typing on the command prompt inside tomcat dir; nor double clicking in the batch file.  https://adoptium.net/ is providing but inside downloaded OpenJDK there is no jre11.

Comment: My best suggestion (again): Describe how you installed Java 11 (or Java 17 if you installed that); describe how you installed Tomcat 10.1; describe how you launch Tomcat - and what value (if any) is set for `%JAVA_HOME%`. And again, searching for a JRE is a red herring (apologies if that phrase is not clear - I mean it's irrelevant and just a distraction). Bottom line: **Help us to take the guesswork out of your situation.** Be specific and precise.

Comment: frankly, I just need for learning purpose only; will try some other day to use [jlink to get jre11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51403071/create-jre-from-openjdk-windows). So currently I have downgraded tomcat version. Thank you for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat10.1 needs Java 11. It does not work with Java 1.8 which I see you are using from the screen cap. See [here](https://endoflife.date/tomcat)

Comment: thankyou @john-Williams, but even the server didn't run even after installing JDK17 and updating the JAVA_HOME. I noticed that JVM will take the javapath var at
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath set automatically by Oracle. I removed it in order to use the new JDK17 but in vain. After noticing that [JRE11 is no more supported by oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53733312/where-is-jre-11); now I am trying [how to get JRE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53111921/how-can-i-get-java-11-run-time-environment-working-since-there-is-no-more-jre-11).