# Passing Command Line arguments to AWS Fargate Container

Tags: spring-boot, terraform, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

We are using Terraform to dynamically spin up an AWS ECS/Fargate container to run a Spring Boot Application and there is a requirement to pass several command line arguments into the application. The available documentation seems to suggest that the correct way to do this is to define a "command" block in the Terraform container definition JSON and specify one or more arguments there. Here is my current container definition:

```
 [{
"name": "${environment}-${app_name}",
"image": "${app_image}",
"cpu": ${fargate_cpu},
"memory": ${fargate_memory},
"networkMode": "awsvpc",
"command": [
   "--server.port",
   "${app_port}"
],
"logConfiguration": {
    "logDriver": "awslogs",
    "options": {
      "awslogs-group": "${environment}-${app_name}",
      "awslogs-region": "${aws_region}",
      "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
    }
},
"portMappings": [
  {
    "containerPort": ${app_port},
    "hostPort": ${app_port}
  }
]}]
```

You will note that I've defined the **command block** with the argument **--server.port** and set its value to the app_port variable. However on deployment this argument **is not** picked up by the Spring Boot application running inside the container and default port is used instead.

My question is simply: how should one go about specifying command line arguments to applications running inside Fargate containers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it because of syntax you are passing the system property.
You can easily test this on your local system before pushing its cloud.

```
docker run -it --net host --rm sprintbootimage java -jar /data/hello-world-0.1.0.jar –server.port=8081
```

This will not work, you can read more details about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44745261/why-do-jvm-arguments-start-with-d/44745321), to make it work you can just simple pass with `-Dserver.port=8081`

```
docker run -it --net host --rm hello-world java -jar -Dserver.port=8081 /data/hello-world-0.1.0.jar
```

ouput

```
2020-07-13 03:31:59.316  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-07-13 03:31:59.631  INFO 1 --- [ main] : Tomcat started on port(s): 8081 (http) with context path ''
2020-07-13 03:31:59.636  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.d.hello.Application                    : Started Application in 4.031 seconds (JVM running for 4.875)
```

[Why do JVM arguments start with "-D"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44745261/why-do-jvm-arguments-start-with-d/44745321)

`-Dproperty=value`

> Sets a system property value. The property variable is a string with no spaces that represents the name of the property. The value variable is a string that represents the value of the property. If value is a string with spaces, then enclose it in quotation marks (for example `-Dfoo="foo bar"`).

So the `CMD` will become

```
  
command: ["java", "-Dserver.port=${app_port}", "-jar", "/data/hello-world-0.1.0.jar"]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So I wanted to clarify two things:
1)In my docker file I use the ENTRYPOINT command to start the application and thus my understanding was that I should be able to pass in JUST the parameters required to start the application to the COMMAND array.
2)I'm well aware of the necessity to prefix JVM properties with "D" however spring boot provides a "shorthand" that essentially makes it possible to specify properties on in the following name/value pair form:  --property.name=value. Thus outside of the container I can do as follows: java -jar app.jar --server.port=80

Comment: Yes you can convert cmd to entry point and for the second point it's not working as you replicate locally as well, so passing with D work perfectly