# Where is yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, yarn-v2

I have looked into:

- log4j2.properties in /etc/spark/conf
- yarn-site.xml
- yarn-env.sh (via `YARN_LOG_DIR` it is not getting set. In fact while running a job there is no env variable `YARN_LOG_DIR` in my executors)
- log4j.properties in /etc/hadoop/conf

Where can I find and modify the `yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find this, we need to traverse some of Hadoop's source code:

- `yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs` [defaults to](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/3262495904d1af03f0f8c77aba69fea6e3122b64/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/src/main/resources/yarn-default.xml#L1407-L1417) `${yarn.log.dir}/userlogs`.
- `yarn.log.dir` [defaults to](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/3262495904d1af03f0f8c77aba69fea6e3122b64/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/shellprofile.d/hadoop-yarn.sh#L54-L56) `$HADOOP_LOG_DIR`
- `$HADOOP_LOG_DIR` [defaults to](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/3262495904d1af03f0f8c77aba69fea6e3122b64/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/bin/hadoop-functions.sh#L898) `${HADOOP_HOME}/logs`

So, have a look at `$HADOOP_HOME/logs/userlogs` to see whether you find something in there!

If you want to edit it, you can do either of the following:

- edit `$HADOOP_HOME`
- edit `$HADOOP_LOG_DIR`
- add `-Dyarn.log.dir=<your_chosen_value>` to your spark application
- add `-Dyarn.nodemanager.log-dirs=<your_chosen_value>` to your spark application

Comment: Thank you Koedlt. :). If we ever meet coffee is on me :).  A small question though, What is the -D flag for? I tried reading it from linux man but that is not super useful

Comment: Haha that would be great! Good question about the `-D` flag, it's very useful knowledge. It stands for "Define", and it is a way to pass arguments to the JVM. Some interesting SO posts about this can be [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44745261/why-do-jvm-arguments-start-with-d) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518728/in-java-d-what-does-the-d-stand-for).